# How to add @Html.ValidationMessageFor for each item in a collection?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

How would you add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each `item` in a `collection`? Say,

```
public class FooVm
{
  // some property
  public ICollection<BarVm> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class BarVm
{
  // some property
  [Range(1, int.Max, ErrorMessage = "Must be greater than 1")
  public float? Fox { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a `view`

```
@model namespace.here.FooVm

<div class="container"></div>
<a href="#" class="trigger">Populate</a>

<script>
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var populate = function() {
    var strBuilder = '<input type="text" name="Bars[i].Fox" />';
    $(".container").append(strBuilder);
    return false;
  };

  $(".trigger").click(populate);
});
</script>
```

It's all working. But how can I add the validation in every `textbox`? I'm using `ASP.NET MVC 4` still practicing. I'm also utilizing `unobtrusive validation` for client validation. Any you-should-do-something-like-this suggestions or tips, sample code would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, using Javascript to populate a View is not the way MVC should be used. Instead, you can render all textboxes like this:

First the code for the class:

```
public class FooVm
{
    // some property
    public List<BarVm> Bars { get; set; }

    public FooVm()
    {
        // Make sure the collection exists to prevent NullReferenceException
        this.Bars = new List<BarVm>();
    }
}

public class BarVm
{
    // some property
    [Range( 1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Must be greater than 1" )]
    public float? Fox { get; set; }
}
```

Now the code for the View:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.FooVm

<h2>Sample View</h2>

@using ( Html.BeginForm( "YourAction", "YourController" ) )
{
    <div class="container">

    @for ( int i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count; i++ )
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Bars[i].Fox )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.Bars[i].Fox );
    }

    </div>
}
```

This will render the necessary tags - and of course the validationmessage-bits. However, it's also possible to combine all error messages in one place by using

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

If you really want to display the stuff only after clicking a button, consider using a partial view and loading that one. That's a much better approach than trying to create all necessary tags and attributes for validation using javascript.

Regards,

Frank

Comment: This is not works! It not validate model in list